# How to save private variables of each Fragment in the Activity during rotate?

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, fragment, restore

I have an Activity with NavigationDrawer, so I have few Fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_menu);

        mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        mMainPageFragment = new MainPageFragment();
        mTestPageFragment = new TestPageFragment();
        mSettingsPageFragment = new SettingsPageFragment();
        mOnlineNeededFragment = new OnlineNeededFragment();
        mRegistrationFragment = new RegistrationFragment();
        mAuthorizationPageFragment = new AuthorizationFragment();

        //Adding fragments to NavigationDrawer

    }

    //selecting Fragment from NavigationDrawer
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = mDrawerMenuItems.get(position).getPage();

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Each Fragment has its private variables, which I save with

```
public class MainPageFragment extends Fragment {

    private int var1;
    private Date var2;
    private Date var3;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            var1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("var1");
            var2 = (Date) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("var2");
            var3 = (Date) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("var3");
        }

        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("var1", var1);
        outState.putSerializable("var2", var2);
        outState.putSerializable("var3", var3);
    }
}
```

and restore in "onCreateView". But all time I rotate screen Activity recreates all Fragments, so I lose my old state in all Fragments.

I found the "getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, TAG, Fragment)". This function can save instance of Fragment to the Bundle and restore it later with "getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, TAG)", so Activity don't recreate this Fragment and don't lose private variables.

But FragmentManager can save only one Fragment, which is in this FragmentManager. When I try to put all Fragments in Bundle, I get exception: "Fragment ProfileFragment{41a27730} is not currently in the FragmentManager".

How can I save all my Fragments in Bundle to restore them after rotating screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies that the onCreate method always creates a new Fragment

```
    mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    mMainPageFragment = new MainPageFragment();
    mTestPageFragment = new TestPageFragment();
    mSettingsPageFragment = new SettingsPageFragment();
    mOnlineNeededFragment = new OnlineNeededFragment();
    mRegistrationFragment = new RegistrationFragment();
    mAuthorizationPageFragment = new AuthorizationFragment();
```

put an if statement to check if it is null.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    mMainPageFragment = new MainPageFragment();
    mTestPageFragment = new TestPageFragment();
    mSettingsPageFragment = new SettingsPageFragment();
    mOnlineNeededFragment = new OnlineNeededFragment();
    mRegistrationFragment = new RegistrationFragment();
    mAuthorizationPageFragment = new AuthorizationFragment();
```

Comment: This variant throws NullPointerException after rotating. I think I need to get instance of Fragments anyway. Either create it or get it from Bundle.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. As onSavedInstanceState is not being called on your Fragments, it may just be being called on your MainActivity where the viewpager resides.   Store your variables in the MainActivity, your Fragments get the data using getActivity(). Then you can use the MainActivity savedInstanceState.

Comment: Seems this is not graceful method, but it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is better practice to store variables in the Activity? I find it keeps the code more centralized.

Comment: Yes, may be it's better. But what exists method "onSaveInstanceState" for in the Fragment class?

Comment: Serves the same purpose, but because the Activity is recreating the Fragments all variables will be wiped clean in the Fragments. Same reason saveInstanceState isn't saved in the Activity when the app is shut down